# Can i use the level class in Bulma using a div element instead of nav?

Tags: html, css, web, bulma

i'm wondering if is right to use the  class level (`class="level"`) with a `<div>` element instead of a `<nav>` which Bulma Docs use.

Thanks in advance!

The Bulma Docs explain it very wella but the examples are only with a `<nav>` element.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Likely yes, because inside the 'bulma.css' CSS utilities file on line 4872 it reads ".level code {...}", and on line 4876 it reads ".level img {...}", both of which are usually used in other places on an html page other than just in a <nav> -- thus html page text that needs formulation using either 'code' and/or 'image'  are often used inside a <div>, etc.

Comment: Yes, at a point in time I wondered too why they so focus on the `nav` element. `Level` is really a great layout concept and I use it a lot in [my project](https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do it all the time, like [here](https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa/blob/main/src/components/CueLevelEditor.vue):

```
    <div class="level is-mobile">
        <!-- Left side -->
        <div class="level-left">
            <!-- Play Button -->
            <div class="level-item">
                <div class="field has-addons">
                    <p class="control">
```

It's working great.

Their [respective sass file](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/components/level.sass) (kind of a "source code" for CSS) suggest that it's working on all block elements:

```
@import "../utilities/mixins"

$level-item-spacing: ($block-spacing * 0.5) !default

.level
  @extend %block
  align-items: center
  justify-content: space-between
```